# WatiN - Set the position of a browser

Tags: c#, watin

Im testing my website using WatiN , and for a specific test I'm opening few IE windows and work on them simultaneously.The problem is that the windows are opened in the same position and i can't see what is going on inside the windows. Any ideas?

I'm looking for something like:

```
var browser=new IE();
browser.SetPosition(top_left_X,top_left_Y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swapping between windows** 
To bring one of the browsers to the front use the browser `BringToFront()` method.

Like:

```
IE ie = new IE();
ie.GoTo("www.cnn.com");
IE secondIE = new IE();
secondIE.GoTo("www.google.com");
secondIE.BringToFront();
```

**Resizing windows**
To resize the windows and make them both viewable, say side by side, I believe you'll need to use something like SetWindowPos() or PInvoke's movewindow().   You can use `ie.hWnd` to get the window pointer to the browser.  Unfortunately it has been a really long time since I've done anything like that and can't put together an example now, or even guarantee it is the right course of action.

Comment: but i want to see both of them

Comment: Updated answer.  Sorry I can't be more of a help on resize.